# MongoDB logs all queries as slow on logging verbosity level 1 and higher

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo db version 4.4.1 and I am profiling for slow queries. With profiling level 1 and verbosity level 0 nothing gets logged, but with profiling level 1 and verbosity level 1 all queries get logged as slow even though durationMillis is lower than slowms. All I found was the official information in the documentation:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiling-levels
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/#db.setloglevel--
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs

> At higher logLevel settings, all operations appear in the diagnostic log regardless of their latency with the following exception: the logging of slow oplog entry messages by the secondaries. The secondaries log only the slow oplog entries; increasing the logLevel does not log all oplog entries.

It is unclear if verbosity level 1 and higher automatically logs all queries as slow.

What is the behavour of the different verbosity levels and why are queries with duratonMillis lower than slowms logged as slow

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is conflating a few related topics, for understandable reasons as we'll see below.

The first pair of concepts are the profiler and slow query logging. The [database profiler](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) is a capped collection that collects runtime information about CRUD operations (among other things). Details about CRUD operations can separately be captured in a log file directly. You adjust both of these using the a single [db.setProfilingLevel() method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/).

Now the aforementioned log file is the same [diagnostic log file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--logpath) that is used by the `mongod` process for its other operational needs. So that single file is serving double duty as it will also capture details about many other components such as networking, replication, and access control. To compound the problem further one of the `components` that can be configured and logged is indeed [the `QUERY` one](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#mongodb-data-QUERY). Adjusting the `verbosity` for `components` is done via the [db.setLogLevel() method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/). The system defaults to a [verbosity level of `0` for all components, which includes "Informational" (`I`) details](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#severity).

Now "slow query" log lines *are* one of the types of messages generated by and are classified as `QUERY` components at the "Informational" level. The result of this fact is that you can increase the number of slow query entries that get logged by either:

- Decreasing the `slowms` threshold via the `db.setProfilingLevel()` method
- Increasing the `verbosity` for the `QUERY` component via the `db.setLogLevel()` method.

Finally to return back to the beginning, slow query logging and profiling also overlap with their usage of the `slowms` (and other related settings). Specifically if you set the (profiling) `level` to `1`, then `slowms` will now be used to control both what entries go into the log file as well as what entries get captured by the profiler. A setting of `0` or `2` makes profiling ignore `slowms` (either not capturing anything in the profiler or capturing everything, respectively).

So the section of the documentation that you quoted, including the sentence before it, is what attempts to tie all of this together (when it comes to behavior on the `PRIMARY`):

> When `logLevel` is set to `0`, MongoDB records slow operations to the diagnostic log at a rate determined by `slowOpSampleRate`. At higher `logLevel` settings, all operations appear in the diagnostic log regardless of their latency

Noting that:

- "slow operations" here are defined as those that exceed the `slowms` setting
- `logLevel` here refers to that `verbosity` setting of `db.setLogLevel()` as opposed to the `level` parameter of `db.setProfilingLevel()`.

I can find no details on why the component strings for the db.setLogLevel() method are [shown in lowercase](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/) yet they [appear to be uppercase](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#components) when logged.

---

Returning back to the original questions with this additional context, the described behavior is aligned with the documented behavior if we tighten up the wording a bit. I assume that the statement about "*profiling for slow queries*" is only about capturing slow queries in the log file. If so, then:

> With profiling level 1 and verbosity level 0 nothing gets logged

That is correct if all of the queries that are executed are also below the `slowms` threshold (which defaults to `100ms`).

> with profiling level 1 and verbosity level 1 all queries get logged as slow even though durationMillis is lower than slowms
>
> It is unclear if verbosity level 1 and higher automatically logs all queries as slow.

That is also correct per the documentation quoted earlier, or the [Logging Slow Operations section here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#logging-slow-operations) which succinctly states that "*Client operations (such as queries) appear in the log if their duration exceeds the slow operation threshold or when the log verbosity level is `1` or higher.*"